# Reading Columns with Some Datetimes and Some Blanks Causes Python Pandas to Read as Objects and not DateTime

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading in an excel spreadsheet that has a column with some datetime stamps and some blanks using pandas with python. The problem I am having is its reading this column as an object instead of datetime64[ns]. I have tried using a converter when reading the sheet to convert it to datetime but this is not working.

I am trying to read in the this column as a datetime so i can convert it to a date and then subtract it from another column I am reading in with date

so

```
df_only_req_fields_merged["Closed Date"] = [d.date() for d in df_only_req_fields_merged["Closed Date"]]
```

but this is failing as the column is an object

and then

```
df_closed_timespan_all['Days to Close'] = (df_closed_timespan_all['Closed Date'] - df_closed_timespan_all['Open Date'])
```

Is there a way I can force pandas to read this in as a datetime?.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to do with your missing dates, but this might work for you:

Say your dataframe looks like this:

```
         col1        col2
0                        
1  2017-12-12  2017-11-12
2  2017-12-12  2017-11-12
3  2017-12-12            
4  2017-12-12  2017-11-12
5                        
6  2017-12-12            
7  2017-12-12  2017-11-12
8  2017-12-12  2017-11-12
9  2017-12-12  2017-11-12
```

Then use `pd.to_datetime` to convert it to a datetime, and then you can subtract one from the other:

```
# Convert your columns:
df['col1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col1'])
df['col2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col2'])
# Make a new column with the time difference between the two columns:
df['col3'] = df['col1'] - df['col2']


>>> df
        col1       col2    col3
0        NaT        NaT     NaT
1 2017-12-12 2017-11-12 30 days
2 2017-12-12 2017-11-12 30 days
3 2017-12-12        NaT     NaT
4 2017-12-12 2017-11-12 30 days
5        NaT        NaT     NaT
6 2017-12-12        NaT     NaT
7 2017-12-12 2017-11-12 30 days
8 2017-12-12 2017-11-12 30 days
9 2017-12-12 2017-11-12 30 days
```

Comment: So i have tried converting the column to a datetime, like you have shown above but then when I check the dtypes of columns my other column which started out as a datetime is now an object which I don't understand

Comment: You probably have some strings in your column that can't be interpreted as a datetime, so it is returning an `object` series

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to change the `dtype` of a column; datatype. See: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html.

Available dtypes can be found here:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dtypes

A convenient wrapper exists as per:

```
pandas.to_datetime("column")
```